# CustomerUserModel and manytomanyfeilds

Tags: python, django, django-models

I currently have a Custom User below which has a one to one model with a model called customer.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None,is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have email address")
        user_obj = self.model(email = self.normalize_email(email))
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")

        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)

        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self,email,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password,is_staff=True)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password, is_staff=True, is_admin=True)

        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # email and password are required by default
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active


class Customer(models.Model):

    GENDER = (
            ('Male', 'Male'),
            ('Female', 'Female'),
            )

    TITLE = (
            ('Mr', 'Mr'),
            ('Mrs', 'Mrs'),
            ('Miss', 'Miss'),
            ('Ms', 'Ms'),
            ('Dr', 'Dr'),
            ('Sir', 'Sir'),
            ('Madam', 'Madam'),
            )



    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=TITLE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    country = CountryField()
    birth_year = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=GENDER)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_purchase = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

However my question is when I need to do a many to many field with another model for example as shown below.

```
class Order(models.Model):

    STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
            )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    b_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    b_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True, default='')
    b_city = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    b_county = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    b_post_code = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

As shown on the order model, is it better to have the foreign key as the User model or the Customer model, when having to do a many to many field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using foreign key is the best approach, as there will be unique record for each order. A customer can create many orders(one to many)(foreign key). but a unique order will not have many customer(many to many) it will have only one customer.